# SetTimout() function that is in the onclick event of a submit button not working

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I have this code at the end of my HTML form, i wanted to do something a few seconds after a the submit button is clicked. However the message is displayed as soon as the button is clicked without the delay, what must i do in order for the delay to work?

```
<input style="width: 99%" type="submit" onclick="setTimeout(alert('hello'), 10000);" value="Update and Close" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the following requirement has to be done like this if the above solution does not work. As you are using a button of type submit you are submitting the form values. To do something after submitting form values(delay in your case) you call javascript on form events.

As I had a similar requirement. I have followed the below approach. Define the function in the head section of the page.

```
<s:form onsubmit="return javascriptfunctionname();">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing correct with setTimeout but use like this

```
onclick="DoLater(); return false;"
```

And the function is

```
function DoLater(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("hello");
  },10000);
}
```

Comment: nice one, but the return false causes the POST to be aborted. Any ideas?

Comment: well as your input is a type of "submit", so I thought you only need some client side code to be executed, that's why added "return false". As per your requirement you can remove it.

Comment: The return false made it work, when i alter it, it stops working. But thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

There's always jQuery, attach to an on click event

http://jsbin.com/omibusU/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<input style="width: 99%" type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" value="Update and Close" />

<script>
function myFunction()
{
 setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},10000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set **javascript:** in onclick

```
<input style="width: 99%" type="submit" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(function(){alert('hello')}, 5000);" value="Update and Close" /></td>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQcS3/)

Comment: You do not need to set javascript

Comment: The same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Following will do

```
onclick="setTimeout(function(){alert('Hello')},3000);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not need to use "return false" use "return fnname"

```
onclick="return fn();" 

function fn() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("hello");
    },1000);
}
```